# How to add About Section in Discord Bot Developed using Discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

I want to add an about me section in the discord bot made by discord.py like this one

[image]

Comment: You can do that in the Discord Developer Portal in the `DESCRIPTION` field of your bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to [Discord Developers Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)
2. Select your application
3. Change the Description field to whenever you want and save (that would be *about me*)

***Voilà!***

[image: Example of About Me]

Answer (score 2):

## You can do this in the developer portal!

#### 1. First go to https://discord.com/developers/applications

#### 2. Then click on the bot you want to add the about section to

[image: Example of the page]

#### 3. Then write your desired about me content in the description field

[image: Screenshot showing where the description field is]

#### 4. Then click save

[image: Screenshot showing the location of the save button]

### Done

Now your bot has the text you entered in the bot's "About Me" section

Comment: @SoumyajoyDas Consider accepting this answer if this helped. That would give both parties some reputation as a bonus

Comment: Ok done @Wasi Master